# Lenove Z570 Brightness Setting Gone in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: screen, brightness

My Lenovo Z570 with Ubuntu 13.10 only now has not brightness controls.  I tried some of the command line hacks (xbacklight and all) and checked all my drivers and bios (all are up to date) but nothing works thus far.

Since there were NO ISSUES with this in Ubuntu 13.04, I have to wonder if someone on the 13.10 team fat-fingered or simply forgot to lay in the coding for that functionality.

Bright screens waste energy and lives are lost in the developing world as a result, so let's get on this friends and resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

the only way to change brightness is to use this command

sudo su

echo 150 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

all other solution does not work at the moment.
this is not my work around. i dont remember where i got this but it works and hats off to the person who gave this workaround :)

Using Ubuntu 13.10 64Bit Wubi on Lenovo Z570

Answer (score 1):

**Try it once hope it works for you also**:

- Open terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> ) and type:

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
  sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
  ```

  You will find this line in the new opened window: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
- Change it to:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
  ```
- Save and close the window and type this in the terminal:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Restart your system..

if above procedure doesn't work then **repeat the same step but** this time try  to change the above mentioned line with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"
```

<sub>**Note:** The next line to the line mentioned above should be `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` not `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I discovered a workaround for Lenovo Z570 and it's quite simple. But it should work for other models too.

Enter the following command in a terminal (you will need the root password to make this work).

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

This will open a text file, with root access. Enter the following text and save the document. Logout and log back in to fix the problem.

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "card0"
Driver "intel"
Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
BusID "PCI:0:2:0"

EndSection
```

The brightness settings should work again.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/) worked for me on Ubuntu 14, Lenovo B570, Intel Graphics!

Open a terminal and create the following configuration file, if it does not exist:

**sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf**

Now we need to edit this file. You can use any editor be it a terminal one or graphical.

**sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf**

Add the following lines to this file:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"

EndSection
```

Save it. Log out and log in back.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/default/grub with anu editor, ej:

sudo mcedit /etc/default/grub

Search GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="..." and add acpi_backlight=none at end run sudo update_grub

this work with intel+nvidia

Reboot!